# Can't run grunt --tasks, not sure what I did, how should I fix?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, yeoman

I'm not sure what I did, but `grunt --tasks` now gives this error:

```
grunt --tasks                                                                                                                                                 

/Users/ivan/dev/frp_play/node_modules/grunt-contrib-compass/node_modules/tmp/lib/tmp.js:261
  throw err;
        ^
TypeError: Arguments to path.join must be strings
    at path.js:360:15
    at Array.filter (native)
    at Object.exports.join (path.js:358:36)
    at Object.file.exists (/Users/ivan/dev/frp_play/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt/file.js:371:28)
    at task.loadTasks (/Users/ivan/dev/frp_play/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt/task.js:358:18)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Task.task.init (/Users/ivan/dev/frp_play/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt/task.js:444:33)
    at Object.grunt.tasks (/Users/ivan/dev/frp_play/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt.js:113:8)
    at Object.module.exports [as cli] (/Users/ivan/dev/frp_play/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt/cli.js:38:9)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt:41:20)
```

The full repo is available here: https://github.com/ivanoats/frp_play

I really can't think of anything out of the ordinary I did. Basically I ran these commands:

```
yo webapp
bower search bacon
bower install bacon
grunt server (worked fine)
bower install bacon --save
grunt serve (broken - no task serve)
grunt --tasks (gives error above)
```

Thanks in advance for your help, suggestions, questions!

Answer (score 0):

D'oh. It's `grunt server`
and `grunt --tasks` is not how you list tasks. I should have RTFM.

Comment: Though we might change that in the future. :) https://github.com/yeoman/yeoman/issues/1183